# Submitting Android TV app with the Same Name as Mobile App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv

Some time ago I developed an Android mobile app with a package name `com.x.y.abc` which is live on the Play Store.

Now, I've developed a separate Android TV (and FireTV) app for the same company which is meant to be used only on TV devices. What is the best way to go about submitting this second app considering that both will share the same app name but have a different package name `(com.x.y.def)`?

*Also, merging the code in the two apps to make just one APK is not an option*

**TL;DR Version**

Need to publish separate Android TV app with the same name as Mobile App.

Comment: Names aren't unique on Google Play, so as long as the package name is different, they're completely separate apps. Is there a reason you're using a different package name at all (vs using [multiple apks](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks))?

Comment: Interesting, I was just looking into multiple APKs. I used different package names to be able to distinguish between the apps running on FireTV, Android TV and Android phones and tablets on platforms like Firebase analytics and more. If I were to go with the multiple apk approach, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: [User properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties) would be the general way of segmenting your analytics into different user populations.